# Serilog equivalent to log4net.Config.Watch?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, serilog

Using log4net it's possible to change the logging settings at runtime by changing the app.config file as long as you have.

```
<add key="log4net.Config.Watch" value="True" />
```

My question is simple: Is there a way to do this for Serilog?

I have read about the LoggingLevelSwitch() class but it looks like that is only changeable through code. Now ofcourse it's possible to program this yourself but I'm looking for a solution baked into Serilog.

Answer (score 0):

*You cannot change the logger configuration at runtime, by changing app.config:* [log4net Documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html)

> Because the System.Configuration API does not support reloading of the
>   config file the configuration settings cannot be watched using the
>   log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch methods. The main
>   advantage of using the System.Configuration APIs to read the
>   configuration data is that it requires less permissions than accessing
>   the configuration file directly.

---

And you cannot do this with Serilog

As you mentioned, log level can be configured at runtime, [Source](https://nblumhardt.com/2014/10/dynamically-changing-the-serilog-level/):

```
var levelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();

levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Warning;

// configuring the logger using log level switch 
var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
   .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelSwitch)
   .WriteTo.ColoredConsole()
  .CreateLogger();

// and you can switch the log level later on
levelSwitch.MinimumLevel = LogEventLevel.Verbose;
```

You can see some options [here](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/485) for changing the Sinks.

Comment: Your comment regarding log4net is not entirely accurate. I use a log4net.config file along with [ConfigureAndWatch](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/html/M_log4net_Config_XmlConfigurator_ConfigureAndWatch_1.htm) where changes to the file (e.g. logging level) are dynamically read in and applied by log4net at run-time.

Comment: My comment about log4net is a quote from official document. Also, the question is about app.config file (you are talking about log4net.config file).

Answer (score 0):

The current Serilog implementation (2.9.0) is such that it is unable to fully reload settings. To work around this issue without introducing additional dependencies, avoid creating static loggers and follow the example provided here: https://github.com/akovac35/Logging/blob/v1.0.4/src/com.github.akovac35.Logging.Serilog/SerilogHelper.cs

```
public static void CreateLogger()
{
    CreateLogger(configure =>
    {
        configure.AddJsonFile("serilog.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
    });
}

public static void CreateLogger(Action<IConfigurationBuilder> configure)
{
    if (configure == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configure));

    UpdateLogger(configure);
}

public static void UpdateLogger(Action<IConfigurationBuilder> configure)
{
    if (configure == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(configure));

    // The following pattern fires the reload token only once per settings change           
    var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    try
    {
        configure(configurationBuilder);
        IConfiguration configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();

        // Release previous callback - will be released only if this line is reached, allowing for another reload
        _changeCallback?.Dispose();
        _changeCallback = null;
        // .NET will not trigger a reload for invalid config file format, so reaching this line signals Json is OK
        _changeCallback = configuration.GetReloadToken().RegisterChangeCallback(state =>
        {
            UpdateLogger(configure);
        }, null);

        // Reading configuration will fail for invalid properties, that is why reload registration must happen
        // before this line or subsequent file updates may not be detected
        global::Serilog.ILogger newLogger = new LoggerConfiguration()
        .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .CreateLogger();

        Log.Logger = newLogger;

        GetLogger().Here(l => l.LogInformation("Updated logger: {@configuration}", configuration));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        GetLogger().Here(l => l.LogError(ex, ex.Message));
    }
}
```

Or you can simply use the [Logging.Serilog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/com.github.akovac35.Logging.Serilog/) library which provides utility functions for just that.